# Regexp to search names of books (Delphi 7 & DiRegEx 8.8.1)

Tags: regex, delphi

I am using Delphi 7 and this is first time I am using the library DiRegEx.
What I need to do is collect names of the books which are in a list. The list is long but to have an idea it looks like this:

2 Tesalonickým 3:14
2 Tesalonickým 3:15
2 Tesalonickým 3:16
2 Tesalonickým 3:17
2 Tesalonickým 3:18
1 Timoteovi 1:1
1 Timoteovi 1:2
1 Timoteovi 1:3
1 Timoteovi 1:4

So what I want to find by RegEx.Match is the '2 Tesalonickým' and '1 Timoteovi' strings. So I want to search for `^some string\d\d?\d?:\d\d?\d?` ...

My code is:

```
var
  contents : TStringList;

  RegEx: TDIRegEx;
  WordCount: Integer;

  s:string;

begin

Contents := TStringList.Create;
RegEx := TDIPerlRegEx.Create{$IFNDEF DI_No_RegEx_Component}(nil){$ENDIF};

Contents.LoadFromFile('..\reference dlouhé CS.txt');
for i:=0 to Contents.count-1 do
  begin
    Contents[i];
    try
      RegEx.SetSubjectStr(Contents[i]);
      RegEx.MatchPattern := '\w+';
      WordCount := 0;
      if RegEx.Match(0) >= 0 then
        begin

          repeat
            Inc(WordCount);
            s := RegEx.MatchedStr;
            WriteLn(WordCount, ' - ', s);
          until RegEx.MatchNext < 0;
        end;
    finally
      RegEx.Free;
    end; // end try
  end; // end for
  end;
```

And I need to modify the regex so the `\d\d?\d?:\d\d?\d?` won't be in the result, but should be an "anchor" or a "needle". How to make the regexp?

**Result:**

This is a complete list of 66 books of bible in UTF-8. There were some problems with the \w pattern because this dos not include characters like Ž or š.

Genesis;Exodus;Leviticus;Numeri;Deuteronomium;Jozue;Soudců;Rút;1 Samuelova;2 Samuelova;1 Královská;2 Královská;1 Paralipomenon;2 Paralipomenon;Ezdráš;Nehemjáš;Ester;Jób;Žalmy;Přísloví;Kazatel;Píseň písní;Izajáš;Jeremjáš;Pláč;Ezechiel;Daniel;Ozeáš;Jóel;Ámos;Abdijáš;Jonáš;Micheáš;Nahum;Abakuk;Sofonjáš;Ageus;Zacharjáš;Malachiáš;Matouš;Marek;Lukáš;Jan;Skutky apoštolské;Římanům;1 Korintským;2 Korintským;Galatským;Efezským;Filipským;Koloským;1 Tesalonickým;2 Tesalonickým;1 Timoteovi;2 Timoteovi;Titovi;Filemonovi;Židům;Jakubův;1 Petrův;2 Petrův;1 Janův;2 Janův;3 Janův;Judův;Zjevení Janovo;

Comment: If that collection is very long and you need a fulltext search, consider database (e.g. SQLite).

Comment: I think bible has about 27 books, so I should collect 27 results. Now I am wondering why this: `s := RegEx.MatchedStr;` `if not bible_books.find(s, index) then bible_books.add(s);` adds multiple records of the books.

Comment: @user1141649 there are more books of the Bible, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_the_Bible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(*UCP)^(?:\d+\s+)?\w+(?=\s+\d\d?\d?:\d)
```

Or

```
(*UCP)^(?:\d+\s+)?\w+(?=\s+\d{1,3}:\d)
```

A `(*UCP)` at the pattern start (PCRE verb) to make all shorthands Unicode-aware.

The patterns match

- `^`  - start of the string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits,
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces and
- `)?` - end  of non-capturing group, 1 or 0 occurrences (`?` makes it optional)
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars...
- `(?=\s+\d{1,3}:\d)` - followed with 1+ whitespaces, 1 to 3 digits, `:` and a digit.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7LEu8v/3).

The `\w` might need replacing with `\p{L}` if you only need to match letters.

Comment: Thank you. I will test this: `(*UCP)^\d? ?\w+(?=\s+\d{1,3}:\d)` for case of Genesis has no digit on the begin.

Comment: @user1141649 Then use `(*UCP)^(?:\d+\s+)?\w+(?=\s+\d{1,3}:\d)`

Comment: When I read as Contents[i]:='Genesis 1:2' the program crashes on line 'RegEx.MatchPattern := '(*UCP)^(?:\d+\s+)?\w+(?=\s+\d{1,3}:\d)';'

Comment: I think the problem was that I must to place `TDIPerlRegEx.Create` in the loop. So now it works, but I need to check the results.

Comment: If you build the pattern in a dynamic way, then you will have to place it inside the loop, although it will worsen the performance.

Comment: @user1141649 Why use them literally? Do you want to say `\w` did not match the Unicode letters even with `(*UCP)` flag?  Did you try `\p{L}` instead as I suggested? Also, you may try using `(*UTF)(*UCP)` (add one more PCRE verb that will allow parsing the string as a Unicode string). So, try 1) `(*UTF)(*UCP)^(?:\d+\s+)?\w+(?=\s+\d\d?\d?:\d)` and 2) `(*UCP)^(?:\d+\s+)?\p{L}+(?=\s+\d\d?\d?:\d)`

Comment: Yet the English version "Song of Songs .." is a bit longer... So here is my update: '(*UCP)^(?:\d+\s+)?[\wŠÈØŽÁéíóášúù]+\s*[\wŠÈØŽÁéóíášúù]*\s*[\wŠÈØŽÁéóíášúù]*(?=\s+\d{1,3}:\d)'. Edit: I am finished now, but next time I will try your suggestion with \p{L} instead \w

Comment: @user1141649 You are doing it wrong. Try `RegEx.CompileOptions := [coUtf8];`